# netstat command doesn't work anymore on the new dedicated server

Tags: freebsd, command, netstat, compatibility

I was using the following command on my previous dedicated server with the same version of the FreeBSD installation:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE #0 r255898: Thu Sep 26 22:50:31 UTC 2013     root@bake.isc.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

The command is following:

```
netstat -ntu -f inet
```

Output:

```
netstat: illegal option -- t
```

Why doesn't it work anymore? I don't have an access to my previous dedicated server so I can't use the `man` to check the differences.

Comment: What's the version of your previous dedicated server? [FreeBSD ManPages Online](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to FreeBSD 8.x (at least as of 8.4-RELEASE) it was possible to use the `-t` option with `netstat -i/-I` (show the state of all network interfaces/a specific interface).

From [FreeBSD 8.4-RELEASE netstat man](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netstat&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%208.4-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html):

```
If -t is also present, show the contents of watchdog timers.
```

This indeed had disappeared from FreeBSD 9.x (see [FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE netstat man](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netstat&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%209.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)).
We can only conclude that it is not possible anymore to check the value of these timers through netstat (if ever these timers have meaning with the 9.x releases).

By the way, `-t` had no meaning with `-n`. So I guess it was not reporting any error because the syntax checker was a bit too permissive but it was adding nothing to your netstat output.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `man` on the [freebsd website](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi)

In short review I see that -t was removed in 9. X branch for [some reasons](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=199992)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah it seems like it is but I wonder if there is any replacement for it , or I just can use the same command without the `-t` argument?

Comment: I dont know what information do you need, but without 
`-t` i will works.